# Dropdown values are not populating

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, jsp

I Can see values coming through in console but the same values are not getting displayed in a webpage(Attached image(s) for easy imagiantion).
Can someone help me with the possible/expected scenarios.

[image]

Can't see values in dropdown.

[image: Values are present in console]
Values are present/seen in console

P.S: It works well when I use Chrome browser and its a cascading menu.

Comment: which encoding are you suposed to use to show this characters?

Comment: Those are english alphabets. I just erased a part in paint.

Comment: Why are you censoring your code, exactly? There's nothing sensitive looking there, :"Sales" "General" "Employee types", all it does is make us think there's an encoding issue

Comment: Okay.. a bit concernced on it. Could anyone help on this? There is no CSS/HTML issue either.

Comment: can you put your code here which you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage of "this" keyword got me in to this problem. While on my research I've used "document.getElementByID" to fetch values dynamically instead this keyword.
Thanks for your time.It's working now.
Edit: Kind of issue to one of my mates, he forgot to add text-size.